# how to find element in div which has Class and is NOT this in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to find an element in div called `wrapper` which has a class of `active` but is not the one I've just clicked.

Here is my code which works if I click on the `.title` class:

```
$(".title").click(function(){
    if ($("#wrapper ul li").hasClass("active")) {
        alert("found one!");
    }
});
```

But i have no idea how to check if its not the one I've clicked. I tried adding `.not(this)` and `.not($(this))` to my if statement to no avail.

I should add i plan to `removeClass` of any that are not the current selected div.

I'm sure I have something wrong somewhere.

for reference heres the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <li class="active">Active Clicked List Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <li>Some Other List Item</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <li>Some Other List Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any Suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: _I should add i plan to removeClass of any that are not the current selected div._ Is this your ultimate goal? Does it actually matter which element you clicked on?

Comment: If you _plan to removeClass_ then why not do that first, before _addClass_ `.active` on the one just clicked one?

Comment: it does matter what element i clicked on yes. I know how to remove classes of the rest, its just finding all except the one ive clicked on

Comment: `.not(this)` should work fine....show the code you tried

Comment: `if ($("#wrapper ul li").hasClass("active").not(this)) {` is what ive tried

Comment: @PaulS. i need to remove the class of any others which are not current. it works better that way

Comment: But you're clicking on `.title` and not inside `#wrapper`

Comment: my mistake, will update code

Comment: .not(this) shouldn't work if this isn't an element in $("#wrapper ul li").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that **your html is invalid**, `DIV` can not be a child of `UL`. Selector is not correct either using `$('.title')` since it is not the class that you are applying `active to`

`hasClass()` returns a boolean, so is not chainable

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but based on code shown you need to use the `not()` filter before `hasClass()`:

```
if ($("#wrapper ul li").not(this).hasClass("active")) {
```

OR

```
if ($("#wrapper ul li.active").not(this).length) {
```

If all it is for is to remove the class, simply remove the active class from all before adding to the current one and you don't need to test for it first

Comment: Works great. Upon seeing this i modified my html and jQuery. I have some bad practises. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Using `not` works fine to exclude an element:

```
$('#wrapper li').click(function(){
  $('#wrapper li').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97DXe/

If you comment out the addClass, you will see that clicking the already active element doesn't remove the class from it.

If you are going to set the active class on the clicked element, it doesn't do much harm to simply remove the class from all the elements first, so then you wouldn't need the `not`.